# SQL query returns DB_E_NOTABLE

Tags: c++, sql-server, mfc

I'm building my first MFC app. I'm successfully connecting to the database, but when I try to execute a query, `hResult` becomes `DB_E_NOTABLE`.

This is my code:

```
class CCitiesTable : public CTable<CAccessor<CCitiesTableAccessor> >
{
       public:

bool SelectAll(CCitiesArray& oCitiesArray)
{
    CDataSource oDataSource;
    CSession oSession;
    CCitiesTable oCitiesTable;

    try 
    {
        HRESULT hResult = CoInitialize(0);

        if (FAILED(hResult))
        {
            //Message( _T("Unable to CoInitialize COM Interface.") );
            return FALSE;
        }
CDBPropSet oDBPropSet(DBPROPSET_DBINIT);
        oDBPropSet.AddProperty(DBPROP_INIT_DATASOURCE,  _T("LENOVO2\\SQL2008") );   // сървър
        oDBPropSet.AddProperty(DBPROP_AUTH_USERID,      _T("sa") );         
        oDBPropSet.AddProperty(DBPROP_AUTH_PASSWORD,    _T("massive") );            
        oDBPropSet.AddProperty(DBPROP_INIT_CATALOG,     _T("PhoneBookDB" ));    
        oDBPropSet.AddProperty(DBPROP_AUTH_PERSIST_SENSITIVE_AUTHINFO,  false);
        oDBPropSet.AddProperty(DBPROP_INIT_LCID,        1033L);
        oDBPropSet.AddProperty(DBPROP_INIT_PROMPT,      static_cast<short>(4));

        // Свързваме се към базата данни
        hResult = oDataSource.Open(_T("SQLOLEDB.1"), &oDBPropSet);

        if (FAILED(hResult))
        {
            //Message(_T("Unable to connect to SQL Server database. Error: %d"), hResult);
            return FALSE;
        }

        //Open session
        hResult = oSession.Open(oDataSource);

        if (FAILED(hResult))
        {
            //Message(_T("Unable to open session. Error: %d"), hResult);
            oDataSource.Close();
            return FALSE;
        }

        //Make query
        CString strQuery;
        strQuery = _T("SELECT * FROM dbo.CITIES");

        // Execute query
        hResult = oCitiesTable.Open(oSession, strQuery);
```

After executing the code above hResult is DB_E_NOTABLE. Except that the table is there. Database: PhoneBookDB Schema: dbo Table: CITIES. The query works just fine in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: are you sure you need the dbo.CITIES and not just CITIES

Comment: Ive tried with dbo.CITIES, CITIES and PhoneBookDB.dbo.CITIES. All of them are not working.

Comment: Where does `oCitiesTable` come from? The only place in the code you show that is at the end. Also: a query is not necessarily a table. You can open a table or you can execute a query but they may require different object types.

Comment: Run a `SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLES` And see if that returns table names.

Comment: It is defined just above the code I posted like :
    ` CDataSource oDataSource;
      CSession oSession;
      CCitiesTable oCitiesTable; `

Comment: @ZachSchulze Changing the query doesnt change the result. Very strange. Im still getting DB_E_NOTABLE

Comment: You don't show those in the code but they are relevant. And what is`CCitiesTable`? What MFC class does it extend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation for [CTable::Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/707cycfa.aspx), `CTable::Open` expects a *table name*, not a select query. The error you are getting is saying that `"SELECT * FROM dbo.CITIES"` is not a table name (which it is not).

> szTableName
>   [in] The name of the table to open, passed as an ANSI string.

You need to use:

```
CString strTable = _T("CITIES");

// Open Table
hResult = oCitiesTable.Open(oSession, strTable);
```